SPO/Teams - User Information List and User Mismatch ID
I face a strange issue :
Owners using Teams and the SharePoint Site associated to it add some guests, to have them access the whole site, or just a folder.
Whatever.
Behaviour observed is that some of those new guests, not everyone of them, have an access denied.
I compared their properties in Entra ID, and they are consistent.
After some digging, I found that those guests have a mismatch ID. I can detect and fix this with the Self Service Diagnostic tool available at https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/?searchSolutions=Diag:%20Site%20User%20ID%20mismatch#/homepage , but I still need to understand the problem.
One thing that we saw afterwards, is that in the User Information List, people are usually displayed like this : Name First Name.
Problematic guest users are displayed by their username. Using the Self Service tool resolves this.
I'm puzzled. Did you ever encounter such an issue in the past ?
